# run access macro within excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want within excel vba to run an access macro and also copy an access query.
When I run the code below, I get an runtime error 3001 on line cn.DoCmd.RunMacro "runCopyqueryVragenlijsten"

```
'~~> Select access file Database Questionmark.mdb
Set cn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
cn.Open "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=D:\Data\Geschiktheidstesten en OPQ-rapport NMBS competenties\Analyse\Database Questionmark.mdb"

'~~> Run access macro
cn.DoCmd.RunMacro "runCopyqueryVragenlijsten"

'~~> Select access query to copy
rs.Open "select * from Copyquery_Vragenlijsten", cn

'~~> paste access query in sheet vragenlijst
Worksheets("vragenlijst").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs

'~~> Close access file and put cursor on cell A1 of sheet evaluatierooster_NL
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: have you checked the spelling of **runCopyqueryVragenlijsten**

Comment: Yes, i have checked it. That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: what happens when you execute *DoCmd.RunMacro "runCopyqueryVragenlijsten"* in MS Access?

Comment: I converted the macro in access to visual basic and this gave me the following codeFunction runCopyqueryVragenlijsten()

    DoCmd.OpenTable "Copyquery_Vragenlijsten", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
    DoCmd.Close acTable, "Copyquery_Vragenlijsten"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "CopyqueryVragenlijsten", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "CopyqueryVragenlijsten"
    DoCmd.OpenTable "Copyquery_Vragenlijsten", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.Close acTable, "Copyquery_Vragenlijsten"

End Function

Comment: everything works fine in access when i run macro

Answer (score 2):

I suggest running the macro separately then connecting to he file and copying the data.

E.g. from http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=13173

```
Sub ExportAccessData()

    Dim mydb As Object

    Set mydb = GetObject("G:\mgai\pertrac\database\StrategyResearch.mdb") 
    mydb.Application.Run "ExportData"  
    mydb.Application.Quit 
    Set mydb = Nothing

End Sub
```

E.g. from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131921

```
Sub Run_Access_Macro()

    Shell("c:\access\msaccess.exe c:\access\sampapps\nwind.mdb")
    Chan = DDEInitiate("MSACCESS", "system") 
    Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftAccess
    DDEExecute Chan, "Sample AutoExec"
    Application.DDETerminate Chan

End Sub
```